# DOM not updating when data changes - Angular 5

Tags: angular

I have a `ProfileImageComponent` that, when clicked, emits the user object it's associated with using my `UserProfileService` service. See this code:

```
export class ProfileImageComponent {

  @Input() user;

  constructor(private userProfileService: UserProfileService, private sidebarService: SidebarService, private storageService: StorageService, private route: Router) { }

  openUserProfile() {
    // mobile
    if(window.innerWidth < 768) {
      this.route.navigate([`/user-profile/${this.user.pk}/`]);
      this.userProfileService.openUserProfile('view', this.user);
    } else {
      // tablet and above
      let loggedInUserPk = JSON.parse(this.storageService.getItem('User'))['pk'];
      let action = this.user['pk'] === loggedInUserPk ? 'edit' : 'view';

      if(!this.sidebarService.sidebarOpened) {
        this.userProfileService.openUserProfile(action, this.user);
        this.sidebarService.openSidebar();
      } else {
        this.sidebarService.closeSidebar();
      }
    }
}
```

Explanation of the above:

On mobile I have a specific route url for the user profile where I route to if the window is smaller than 768px. The line after the route emits an action and the user object associated.

On tablet and above we instead open a sidebar which doesn't require a route change - it emits the value and opens the sidebar.

The `UserProfileComponent` that subscribes to the emitted value **does receive the value** regardless of screens. Here's its `OnInit`:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.userProfileSubscription = this.userProfileService.userProfile$
      .subscribe((profile) => {
        this.canEditProfile = profile['action'] === 'edit' ? true : false;
        this.user = profile['user'];
        this.cdr.markForCheck();
      });
  }
```

In my HTML I just want to display the data at this stage:

```
<div id="user-profile">
  <p>User : {{ user | json }}</p>
</div>
```

**The problem:** 
The data doesn't display on mobile unless I click twice, even though the data is definitely getting there and the model is being updated.

I tried to mark it for change detection but it didn't work (`this.cdr.markForCheck();`)

I also tried adding the `| async` pipe to the user object in the HTML but it didn't change either.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

The `UserProfileService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class UserProfileService {

  private userProfileSource = new Subject<any>();
  userProfile$ = this.userProfileSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  openUserProfile(action, user) {
    this.userProfileSource.next({ action: action, user: user });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Router.navigate is asynchronous. The problem is probably that you emit your data (through `this.userProfileService.openUserProfile('view', this.user)` before the `OnInit` in `UserProfileComponent`.

You can use a [BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject) in your `userProfileService` that will replay the last value emitted during the `OnInit`.

Comment: I do do that. I'll edit my post above to demo the service. If it gets the data update it should still update the template

Comment: (from doc linked above) One of the variants of Subjects is the BehaviorSubject, which has a notion of "the current value". It stores the latest value emitted to its consumers, and whenever a new Observer subscribes, it will immediately receive the "current value" from the BehaviorSubject. ===> Could you try with a BehaviorSubject instead a plain Subject ?

Comment: Sure - I'll give it a shot. Will report back.

Comment: It appears to have worked. I'll need to do more reading to understand why this works and test it. Cheers.